# Is there a way to delete unneeded keyframes automatically?

Tags: animation, workflow

I made an animation by keying every bone in the rig on every keyframe.

Now I have a lot of extra keyframes, as some bones didn't move at all, remaining the same for all keyframes.

Is there a way to delete these extra keyframes automatically?
And are there any "good practices" to help prevent this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.

In the Dope Sheet, select all channels by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> while hovering over the list of channels, then press <kbd>O</kbd>. All unnecessary keyframes will be erased.

Comment: Doesn't this also mess with the clamps/tangents?

Comment: @Laambi What are these clamps/tangents?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms They are the handles/sticks you manipulate in the Graph Editor. They are highlighted in this picture: http://wiki.blender.org/uploads/thumb/b/b2/Doc26-fcurve-extrapolate2.png/300px-Doc26-fcurve-extrapolate2.png

Comment: And I don't remember where I read so, but I think "O" resets them to a preset. Just worth noticing, so you don't erase days of work ;)