# Is there a way to delete unneeded keyframes automatically with v2.79?

Tags: keyframes

This is outdated:
[Is there a way to delete unneeded keyframes automatically?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-there-a-way-to-delete-unneeded-keyframes-automatically/18236?s=1|34.0274#18236)

Pressing [ O ] now activates proportional editing in the action editor. So how can I delete all the useless keyframes that populates the middle of the lines of orange stripes in the action editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now to achieve the same result, while hovering the dope sheet or the graph editor press 'X'.
From there you'll have the possibility to use the 'clean keyframes' option or 'clean channels'.

[image: Clean the keyframes]

If you want to access it through the menu, just click the 'key' option and from there you can access the 'clean keyframes' (as shown above).